# File does not exist at path Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, file-upload, filesystems

I have an issue with uploading, when I try to upload a file in to the host server that is bigger than around 4MB I get an error:

> File does not exist at path {$path}

[image: picture of an error]

In local server I can upload any size I want, tried 7MB+. I though this is a validation issue, so I did 'max:20840' for around 20MB. Is this more related to host provider or my code?

Comment: Are you uploading or downloading the file? Because the error should occur when you get the file. Could you show us your code?

Comment: I am using this plugin for interface : http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input and here is my code. 

`$file = $request->file('contract_upload');
        if($file != null){
        foreach ($file as $key) {
            $extension = $key->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Storage::disk('local')->put($key->getFilename().'.'.$extension,    File::get($key)); ` it's just a part of code, due to comment limitation.

Comment: The code seems correct. If you can upload files locally without problems, maybe the issue is related with your host provider. Try to compare the results of both phpinfo() servers.

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: If you have additional information for your question please [edit] the question to add it. While you can respond to people in comments, all pertinent information should be edited into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you change upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in php.ini?

if not then change it and try again

upload_max_filesize = 100M

post_max_size = 100M

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply, sadly this didin't work.

Comment: **Quick edit:** It worked, I edited the wrong files, appratenly there are 2 php.ini files :)